# Approval Workflow Any user to Approve

Tags: workflow

I'm using the OOTB Approve Workflow..

When I add two people person1 and person2 in the Approvers field they **both** need to approve for the workflow to end. I want when **either** person approves then  workflow ends. How can this happen?

Is there a reason why this functionality isnt in the OOTB?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to put both of the users in a group and there is an option to expand the task for all users in the group. You DON'T want this checked. Without this it will create a single task for the whole group. When that single task is completed the workflow should be complete.

Comment: Thats worked. There is already an Approvers group in the site collection, I've used this for the moment but I need different users for different types of approvals, should I create more groups? its a shame I need to use groups as using individual names would have been easier I think. I only have one site collection hence the single Approver group

Comment: Yes you can create as many groups and the permission levels on the list will determine who can approve what in addition to the form level security on the tasks. Just make sure the approvers have access to the list the workflow is on as well as the task list.